# To Find the height of the building

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

A building casts a shadow 50 feet long.
A rod 4 feet tall placed near the building casts a shadow 3 inches
long. Find the height of the building.

Comment: Do you happen to have the correct answer? It seems like you could just use the given information to create a ratio and find the shadow for the large building.

Comment: @mathtastic Yes, it looks like they are just asking for MSE to do their homework for them.

Answer (score 2):

Four feet is 48 inches.

${48\over 3}={x\over{50}}$
x is in feet.

Comment: sorry about that! You definitely got it.